# How can I use an object as input?

Tags: java, object, constructor

The question is-
Define the class Passenger and TrainCoach and create an object of TrainCoach from `String[]`.Define a class `Passenger` having the fields name (`String`), age (`int`), gender (`char` : M/F), weight (`int`)
Define a class `TrainCoach` having the fields `Passenger[]` passengers
You have been given a `String[]` as input.Create the `TrainCoach` object given the `String[]` as input.

- `public int numberOfPassengers()` : returns the number of passengers in the coach.
- `public int numberOfChildren()` : returns the number of children in the coach. Anyone below the age of 16 is to be considered as a child.
- `public int totalWeight()` : returns the total weight of all the passengers in the coach.

I am unable to write the logic for numberOfChildren()  and totalweight().Following is what I have tried.Please explain what I did wrong.

```
package Passenger;

 public class Passenger {
    String name;
    int age;
    char gender;
    int weight;  
    public Passenger(){}
        public Passenger(String data){
                String[] s=data.split(":");
                this.name=s[0];
                this.age=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
                this.gender=s[2].charAt(0);
                this.weight=Integer.parseInt(s[3]);
        }
        public Passenger[] makePassenger(String[] input){
            Passenger[] passengers=new Passenger[input.length];
            for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
                passengers[i]=new Passenger(input[i]);
            }
            return passengers;
        }
}

package Passenger;

public class TrainCoach {
    Passenger[] passengers;
    public TrainCoach(){}
    public TrainCoach(Passenger[] passengers){
        this.passengers=passengers;
    }


    public static class PassengerTest{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String[] str={"Amit Sharma:24:M:72","Rahul:12:M:55"};
            Passenger pass=new Passenger();
            Passenger[] passenger=pass.makePassenger(str);
            TrainCoach traincoach=new TrainCoach(passenger);
            int c=traincoach.numberOfPassengers();
            int d=traincoach.numberOfChildren();
            int b=traincoach.totalWeight();
            System.out.print(c+","+d+","+b);
        }
    }
    public int numberOfPassengers(){
        return this.passengers.length;
    }
    public int numberOfChildren(){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i=i+4){
            if(i<16){
            count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public int totalWeight(){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i=i+2){
            sum+=i;
        }
        return sum;
    }


}
```

Comment: In your `numberOfChildren()` why are you incrementing `i` by `4`? and similarly in `totalWeight()` why are you incrementing `i` by `2`?

Comment: numberOfPassengers: You want to report how many passengers were actually in the array, not the array length (maximum number of passengers).

Comment: I incremented it by 2 and 4 because age and weight are present at this position repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int numberOfChildren(){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
        if(passengers[i].age < 16){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
public int totalWeight(){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
        sum+=passengers[i].weight;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanku vry much for ur help.

Comment: your welcome. but i suggest you to read all comments and answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are only dealing with the loop counter when you're making your calculations. You need to look at the `Passenger` objects. Here's how you can fix `totalWeight()`, you can use it as an example for how to fix `numberOfChildren()`

```
public int totalWeight(){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++) { // Use ++ (or += 1) instead of +2. You want to look at every passenger, not every other one.
        Passenger pass = passengers[i]; // Get the passenger at the ith position in the array
        if (pass != null) { // Avoid null pointer exceptions when the train isn't full
            sum+= pass.getWeight(); // Add that passenger's weight to the sum
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You'll need to add the `getWeight()` method to your passenger class too.

A good way to spot mistakes like these is to do what I have done here and put a comment on each line describing in plain English what the line does. This makes it easy to spot mistakes in your algorithm.

You may also want to make your `Passenger.makePassenger()` method static so you don't need to make a `Passenger` to call it. Instead of:

```
Passenger pass=new Passenger();
Passenger[] passenger=pass.makePassenger(str);
```

You would only need to do:

```
Passenger[] passengers = Passenger.makePassenger(str);
```